# Simplest way to modify an existing java application and get it online

Tags: java, playframework

I have a standalone application in java. It works by calling the main function. So right now I have to get this java application up and running online with a GUI.There arent too many people who are going to use it. Its more for testing purposes. I was wondering which java web framework I would have to use to get it to work in the shortest time? Since I havent worked much on Java webframeworks I am kind of lost. I cam across http://www.playframework.com/. Is it good to use? Also are there any better solution out there?
For the GUI part I probably have to create a form online also. Whats the right way to go from  here?

Comment: First step. Ensure that the bussiness logic is detached from the GUI.

Comment: Right now I have no GUI . I just have an object into which I pass some parameters manually and it seems to work. Its more like a command line application right now

Comment: What SJuan76 is saying is, that the main class in your application is hopefully instanciating some classes. You can use these classes in your web application as well (mostly). Everything that was implemented in the main class either needs to be moved into other classes or implemented in your web application by hand. You could use java server pages (JSP) for the GUI and java calls.

Comment: Do you think its better to use plain java servlets or use a web framework? Its just a single form and the output has to call some classes and display the data? DO you think using a framework is required in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have an OO code, rather than every LOC in main method, then you are already half way done.

Go to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693422/which-j2ee-web-development-framework-to-choose-for-a-simple-accessible-applicat) to decide on MVC

Answer (score 0):

If you have a method

```
public String echo(String text) { ... }
```

this might be a Solution:

In your Application you just need to remove the `void` from from `public static void main(String[] args)` 
[image]

Just install JBoss